# phpmyadmin on read only slave

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'd like to get phpmyadmin running to read against multiple slaves I have.  I have a couple problems.

1. Since these are slaves I would really like to have them running in read only mode.  The phpmyadmin user has only select access so it's not that which I'm worried about.  It's just more the configuration principle of it that no users should be able to write to a slave.
2. I've been able to get it running with multiple servers to select from easily enough (albeit *not* in read only mode for the moment).  Another annoyance is it seems to require a phpmyadmin database on *each server*.  This is annoying as I have to add the user to each slave.

Really I'd like to be able to tell it to use an entirely different server for the phpmyadmin database.  That way I can have the actual slaves in read-only mode, and I can just have a single pmadb for all slaves involved.

I've read over the docs and it really just seems like this is not possible.  It only seems to allow the specification of a 'pmadb' (not a pmadb-host, etc).

Having the phpmyadmin database is a requirement as there are users that want the bookmark feature.

Is there any way to accomplish what I want?

I'm running PMA 3.2.2

Comment: I'm fairly certain at this point this just isn't possible. I've just created a feature request for the project https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3485898&group_id=23067&atid=377411

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an alternate host for the phpmyadmin database in config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = ...;
```

Doc: http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html